# Word VBA SelectContentControlsByTag collection out of order?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a Word template form using ContentControl fields for drop down lists. I made a macro to take each content control tagged "required" and check if it's showing placeholder text. If it is, it throws up a message box asking the user to fill in the required fields, and IDEALLY jumps to the bookmark for that content control box.

After a lot of iteration and troubleshooting, it can in fact do that, but I've noticed that the Collection of required fields is in..... a random order. I tested this by adding another content control dropdown named "jimmy" at the bottom of the Word document and then looked in the collection and saw it was in the middle of all the other required fields.

Does anyone know how the "SelectContentControlsByTag" method decides on its order, and if there's a robust way to make it use the order that they're placed in the document? I have a decent amount of coding experience but I'm entirely self-taught as far as VBA goes, so I'd appreciate the help!

Here is my current code (Doc is set in Document_New, and the bookmark jump isn't in currently, I'm just checking the order in VBA/the message box)

```
Set reqFields = Doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("required")
For Each iField In reqFields
    If iField.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
        Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response
        Msg = "The dropdowns marked with * cannot be left blank. Do you want to select a response before exiting? Box: " & iField.Title    ' Define message.
        Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1    ' Define buttons.
        Title = "Warning: Empty fields"    ' Define title.
            ' Display message.
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
        If Response = vbYes Then
            Doc.Saved = False: SendKeys "{ESC}"
            'iField.Range.Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Exit For
    End If
'Exit Sub
Next iField
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question but by doing `Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response`, you are declaring all of them as `Variant` since you did not specify the data type. You should try to declare all variables with proper data type such as `Dim Msg as String, Style As VbMsgBoxStyle, Title As String, Response As VbMsgBoxResult`

Comment: Noted! I copied/modified that from.... somewhere, lol. I'll clean that up, thanks!

Comment: AFAIK neither `SelectContentControlsByTag` or `SelectContentControlsByTitle` use an index, so I would expect the results to be pretty random. Why are you using bookmarks when you already have a pointer to the content control and can just select it?

Comment: I think I had my terms confused, you can see up there I had the Range.Select commented out so that is what I'm doing now. And I might be mistaken but I think it does use an index? Or at the very least, reqFields.Item(i) will get me a specific item in that collection. I'm just wondering why the items aren't in any sort of discernable order, even though it's a *consistent* out-of-order.

Comment: They create an index to the collection that they build, but don’t use the content controls index. That’s why the order is random.

Comment: Ah. So am I just SOL here?? I'd really like to check them in order, so that the page jumps to the next empty field starting from the top, but I can't think of a way that doesn't require bespoke names for all of the content controls.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being 10 months late in answering!
When you use .selectcontentcontrolsbytag VBA will loop through the existing content controls by .ID to pull out the tag name.  So if you want your ("tag").item(1) to be ordered you first need to put your content controls in ascending order by .ID number.

Comment: Where do you see this .ID Number?